# inline progress bar animation, change trigger to scroll from load?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, scroll, progress-bar

I recently came across [this article](https://css-tricks.com/animate-to-an-inline-style/) on animating a progress bar inline. I want to use this exact code, but want it to get triggered when someone sees it as they scroll down. Currently, that code gets triggered on load.

I'm basically trying to figure out the easiest way to achieve what these folks did on the "how it works" section: https://join.com/.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using [scroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll) event, that will trigger **scrollTrigger()** and there you should get the [scroll Top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop) then calculate height and progess finally set the css style and the text when scrolling, i think it's clear :)

```js
window.onscroll = function() { scrollTrigger() };

function scrollTrigger() {
 var scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
 var height = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;
 var progess = (scrollTop / height) * 100;
 document.getElementById( 'progressbar' ).style.width = progess + "%";
 document.getElementById( 'progressbar' ).innerHTML = "Upload is " + Math.round( progess ) + "% complete"
}
```

```css
body { background: black; padding: 100px; margin: 0;height: 900px; }

.progress-bar{
 width: 100vw;
 height: 40px;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: #fff
}

.progress-bar > div { 
  color: white; 
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  padding: 10px 0px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 0%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress-bar">
    <div id="progressbar">0%</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, scrollTop() gives the position and scrollHeight gives the height of the scroll bar. On scroll event, set the width of progess-bar with respect to the position of scroll bar

```js
jQuery('div').on('scroll', function(event){
var top = jQuery('#scroll_container').scrollTop();
var height = jQuery('#scroll_container').scrollHeight;
var width = top/height * 100;
jQuery('#progess-bar').css('width', width+"%");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Waypoint JS Plugin.

http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/

I've created a Codepen, where you can see how it works.

[Codepen Animation triggered on scroll](https://codepen.io/digitalgizmo/pen/pYjNPX)

You can change the offset as you desire. Check out the Waypoint Documentation here: [Waypoint](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/api/offset-option/)

```js
$('#scroll-to').waypoint(function() {
  $(".animated-bar").css({ 
      WebkitAnimationPlayState:"running",
      animationPlayState:"running"
      });
},{offset: 150} );
```

```css
/* Animate to natural width */

body { background: black; padding: 100px; margin: 0; }

.progress-bar {
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 14px;

}
.animated-bar { 
  color: white; 
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  
  animation: progress-bar 2s;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes progress-bar {
   0% { width: 0; }
}

h1{
  color:white;
}

.scroll-box{
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-box">
  <h1>Scroll Down</h1>
</div>
<div class="progress-bar" id="scroll-to">
  <div class="animated-bar" style="width: 75%">Upload is 75% complete</div>
</div>
<div class="scroll-box"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/1.1.6/waypoints.min.js'></script>
```